# Joomla K2 Blog (Content Module) not linking to article, stays at home

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

This is probably a bug or a lack of understanding on my part on SEF. The site is: new.bloquelifestyle.com

To reproduce my problem click on "read more" or the title of the article, and as you can see you will go to (for example) http://www.new.bloquelifestyle.com/index.php/68-new-website but the module won't actually leave home (frontpage slider should only display on home, yet is still there when you click on an article). Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have encountered that problem. It has a strange but easy solution:

1. Open Menu Manager:
2. Create a new menu (let's say fake menu)
3. Add a menu item with type of "Category List" to the main menu.
4. And choose the category from right section. The category can be your article's parent category

You do not have to display the menu on the page as module.